# Non linear DC voltage conditioning

Tags: analog, voltage-measurement, non-linear

I do not want to use any adc or dac. I want to see if this is possible by pure analog circuit. Any google links or book names are welcome. From 0 to 1000mV output should be 0 to 100mV. Then from 1001mV to 2000mV output should be 10mV to 20mV from the same terminal.

Comment: *You can clealrly see this is non linear.* — No, I can't. You need a 1:100 voltage divider.

Comment: Janka sir, i modified the question have a look.

Comment: Maybe graphing out what you want the response  to be would be clearer.

Comment: So, if the output is 15 mV it could either be the input was 150 mV or 1500 mV? There is no need to distinguish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a precision comparator with a really tiny bit of hysteresis to decide whether the input is above or below 1000.5 mV. Use the comparator output to select one of two signals using a transmission gate or multiplexer.

- Signal 1 is the input potted down by 10:1
- Signal 2 is the input potted down by 100:1

Use very good precision resistors and don't expect it to be seamless if there is noise on the DC signal or the "so-called" DC voltage is an AC signal.

Comment: Can't this be done without multiplexer.

Comment: How accurate do you need it to be - yes is the answer but it depends on your accuracy requirement.

Comment: 0 to 100mV with 1mV error(1%). 10mV to 20 mV with 1mV error(10%).

Comment: You can use an open-drain comparator.  Make a voltage divider with, say, 100K to the input and 10K to ground, with a 1.1K going from the divider output to the comparator output.

Comment: Or, use a MOSFET to convert the pot divider to the bigger division ratio. Leakage might be a problem of course.

Comment: Good idea andy. Looking into open drain comparator system cristobol.